# Shared Cookies between Expo AuthSession and Safari on iOS with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, cookies, expo

I'm working on a React Native Expo App and trying to create a web-auth login-flow using AuthSession. It works perfectly on Android but the cookies is not stored on iOS. The flow is like so:

1. Open AuthSession
2. Login with browser form and get JWT
3. Save JWT as cookie and send it back to app as query param for later use
4. Open native browser and auto-login with stored cookie

The last step[4] is the issue - the cookie is not stored in safari. This means the user needs to login again after they already loggedin through the app.

As I understand expo's documentation - AuthSessions should always share cookies with the system browser unless `preferEphemeralSession` is set to `true` [reference](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/#authsessionopenoptions)

Thanks in advances - I would be glad to elaborate further if needed :)